# Cannot group by Year, Month and Date C#

Tags: c#

I would like to know how I can group dates by year, month and date respectively.

So far I managed to group by month and date, however I am getting some trouble understanding to group b a year

So, I created several classes that represent Day, Month and Year:

```
public class Day
{    
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Month
{
    public int MonthNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Day> Days { get; set; }
}

public class Year
{
    public int YearNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Month> Months { get; set; }
}
```

So first I got a range of dates overall and add them to list of days.

```
var startDate = DateTime.Parse("12/08/2019");
var endDate = DateTime.Parse("01/03/2020");
var days = new List<Day>();
var months = new List<Month>();
var years = new List<Year>();
if (endDate >= startDate)
{
    for (var date = startDate; date <= endDate; date=date.AddDays(1))
    {
        var dayModel = new Day();
        dayModel.Date = date;
        days.Add(dayModel);
    }
}
```

Then I tried to group days by months and add them to list of Months:

```cs
var grouppedMonths = days.GroupBy(y => y.Date.Month).ToList();

foreach (var month in grouppedMonths)
{
    var monthModel = new Month();
    monthModel.Days = month.Select(d => d).ToList();
    months.Add(monthModel);
}
```

After groupping by months I want to group actual result by the year.
I tried something like this:

```
var grouppedYears = months.GroupBy(x => x.Days.Select(y => y.Date.Year));
```

but it did not work for me.
Overall I want to get

- list of years

  - that contain list of months

    - that contain list of days.

Comment: You are loosing the Date.  So if grouping my months I use following : days.GroupBy(y => new DateTime(y.year, y.month, 1));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
var results = days
    .GroupBy(d => d.Date.Year)
    .Select(y => new Year
    {
        YearNumber = y.Key,
        Months = y
            .GroupBy(d => d.Date.Month)
            .Select(m => new Month
            {
                MonthNumber = m.Key,
                Days = m.ToList()
            })
            .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```